# How can i scroll through all my movies in a loop (carousel like)

Tags: android, video, scroll

I have 3 movies attached to a `VideoView` and 3 buttons: `back`, `forward` and `home`.

I want to scroll through them with the `back` - `forward` buttons in a loop.
When I reach the last movie clicking on `forward` key, I want the first movie to start again and the same with `back` key, when I reach the first movie the last one to start.

I know its probably an easy question, but I'm new to android, and I just can't figure it out.

Thank you very much!!!

This my main activity code:

```
public class Blue extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

ImageButton back;
ImageButton home;
ImageButton forward;
VideoView vid;
int count_back=2;
int count_fw=1;
String urlpath1;
String urlpath2;
String urlpath3;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blue);

    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);
    home = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.home);
    home.setOnClickListener(this);
    forward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.forward);
    forward.setOnClickListener(this);


    vid = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

    urlpath1 = "android.resource://"+ getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.blue_01;
    urlpath2 = "android.resource://"+ getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.blue_02;
    urlpath3 = "android.resource://"+ getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.blue_03;

    vid.setVideoPath(urlpath1);
    vid.requestFocus();
    vid.start();
}

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch(v.getId()){

            case R.id.home:
                vid.stopPlayback();
                Intent i = new Intent(Blue.this,MainActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            case R.id.forward:
                if(count_fw==0){vid.setVideoPath(urlpath1);count_fw++;count_back=2;vid.requestFocus();
                vid.start();}
                else if(count_fw==1){vid.setVideoPath(urlpath2);count_fw++;count_back=0;vid.requestFocus();
                vid.start();}
                else if(count_fw==2){vid.setVideoPath(urlpath3);count_fw=0;count_back=1;vid.requestFocus();
                vid.start();}
                break;

            case R.id.back:
                if(count_back==0){vid.setVideoPath(urlpath1);count_back=2;count_fw=1;vid.requestFocus();
                vid.start();}
                else if(count_back==1){vid.setVideoPath(urlpath2);count_back--;count_fw=2;
                vid.requestFocus();vid.start();}
                else if(count_back==2){vid.setVideoPath(urlpath3);count_back--;count_fw=0;
                vid.requestFocus();vid.start();}
                break;
        }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
        vid.stopPlayback();
      super.onDestroy();

}
```

}

Comment: I managed to figure it out using the switch & case statement, and reposted the code. Hope someoane finds this useful. Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 public class Blue extends Activity {

ImageButton back;
ImageButton home;
ImageButton forward;
VideoView vid;
int count_back;
int count_fw;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_blue);

    back = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);
    home = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.home);
    forward = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.forward);

    vid = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

    final Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.blue_01);
    final Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.blue_02);
    final Uri uri3 = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.blue_03);

    vid.setVideoURI(uri1);
    vid.requestFocus();
    vid.start();
    count_back=2;
    count_fw=1;

    home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            vid.stopPlayback();
            Intent i = new Intent(Blue.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });



    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(count_back==0){
           vid.setVideoURI(uri1);
           vid.requestFocus();
           vid.start();
           count_back=2;
           count_fw=1;
            }
           else if(count_back==1){
           vid.setVideoURI(uri2);
           vid.requestFocus();
           vid.start();
           count_back--;
           count_fw=2;
            }
           else if(count_back==2){
           vid.setVideoURI(uri3);
           vid.requestFocus();
           vid.start();
           count_back--;
           count_fw=0;
            }


        }
    });



    forward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if(count_fw==0){
            vid.setVideoURI(uri1);
            vid.requestFocus();
            vid.start();
            count_fw++;
            count_back=2;
            }
            else if(count_fw==1){
            vid.setVideoURI(uri2);
            vid.requestFocus();
            vid.start();
            count_fw++;
            count_back=0;
            }
            else if(count_fw==2){
            vid.setVideoURI(uri3);
            vid.requestFocus();
            vid.start();
            count_fw=0;
            count_back=1;
            }


        }
    });


}

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        if (vid != null)
            vid.stopPlayback();
          super.onDestroy();

}

}
```